# how does the installer creates other needed files beside the main exe?

Tags: c#, windows-installer, installation

i develop a windows service in C#. and my project has Installer, and Setup project. the setup project, installs service very well and it doesn't have any problem, but my service 'exe' needs some files beside own. for example config files or other needed files. but the installer(setup.exe) just creates service 'exe' file. 
how do i define that the installer creates other needed files, too?

thanks,

Comment: You may want to include more tags to get an answer, i.e. installer project, VS installer, etc., if they exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps given below,

1. Select the Installer project.
2. Select `File System Editor` under Solution Explorer
3. Select `Application Folder` under File System on Target Machine pane.
4. Right click on the UI and add whatever the file you want to pack with the installer.

[image]